# Using php how to match boolean value with word in sentence?

Tags: php, string, boolean, match

I have a response from aws like this with boolean value :

```
 $string=/vasff/fdsfsdf:boolean true
and $string=/sadasff/fdsfsdf:boolean false
```

in their documentation, they had written a response in boolean.// Success? (Boolean, not a CFResponse object).

Their documentaion is [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_doesObjectExist](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_doesObjectExist.)

how to match value is true or false? I tried this code but it always returns true.

```
if(stripos($string, true) !== false){
echo "true";
}
else{
echo "false";
}
```

**EDIT**

Just wanted to thank everyone for their good answers on this.
This code is working fine for aws s3 bucket response.

```
if($response == FALSE){
 return false; }else{
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Your first code part is strange (and not valid PHP), are the `true` and `false` inside the string or not? It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve here, as `stripos` looks for a string in another string, not a boolean. From the docs: "If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character. "

Comment: I am getting this response from AWS API if the file already exists then  response-> /vasff/fdsfsdf:boolean true and file is not exist then response->/vasff/fdsfsdf:boolean false then how to match true and false boolean. I am not getting an array. Kaddath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean by this :

```
$string=/vasff/fdsfsdf:boolean true
```

this :

```
$string='/vasff/fdsfsdf:boolean true';
```

you can use this code : use `true` with double quote

```
$string='/vasff/fdsfsdf:boolean true';
if(stripos($string, "true") !== false){
    echo "true";
}
else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Edit : 
use your function paramaters intead of `....`

```
if(doesObjectExist(....)){ 
    echo "true"; 
}else{ 
    echo "false"; 
}
```

Comment: always return false.

Comment: I tested this code with `$string='/vasff/fdsfsdf:boolean true';`
and with
`$string='/vasff/fdsfsdf:boolean false';`
and its work fine

Comment: response is either /vasff/fdsfsdf:boolean true
or /sadasff/fdsfsdf:boolean false. in their documentation, they had written a response in boolean.// Success? (Boolean, not a CFResponse object).

Their documentaion is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_doesObjectExist

Comment: are you use this function `doesObjectExist` ? if yes its seems return true directly

Comment: no it is returning either /var/www/html/aws-file-exist.php:62:boolean true or /var/www/html/aws-file-exist.php:62:boolean false. and true and false is in higlighted color(boolean value).

Comment: alright then use 

    `if(doesObjectExist(....)){
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }`
replace `....` with your function parameters

Comment: var_dump thats return /vasff/fdsfsdf:boolean true not doesObjectExist
you can use echo instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
preg_match_all("/:boolean (.+)/", $string, $mc);
if(isset($mc[1]) && isset($mc[1][0])){
    if($mc[1][0] == "false"){
        echo $mc[1][0] . " == false";
    }
    else{
        echo $mc[1][0] . " == true";
    }
}
```